# Javascript enable button ie6

Tags: javascript

I have a change password screen and when the 2 passwords match i need to enable the save button. It works with IE8 + IE7 but fails to enable the button in IE6

```
        var LblError = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphValNet_LblError');
        var Pwd1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphValNet_txtNewPassword')

        var Pwd2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphValNet_txtNewPassword2')

        var Change = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphValNet_BtnUpdatePassword')
        // code to check if password matches
        Change.disabled = false;
```

Any ideas why this is happening

Sp

Could the RegEx be causing the issue?

```
function IsalphaNumericValidate(alphanumericChar) {
        if (alphanumericChar.length < 6 || alphanumericChar.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g) != -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
            return re.test(alphanumericChar);

        }           
    }
```

Comment: What is alphanumericChar? Is it the field? The value? Or a single character from the field value?

Comment: alphanumericChar is the value of the password field

Comment: Ive put some debug code in and it's showing that ie6 is returning false to a valid password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
Change.disabled = false;
```

try

```
Change.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

## [demo](http://jsbin.com/unehu3)

Comment: Stille the same issue, works fine with ie7 + ie8 + chrome but not ie6.
:(

Comment: Your demo works perfect, must be the checking part of my JavaScript.

Comment: Ive added the regex check can you glance over it and see if ive made and errors that ie6 would have issues with?